# CodeWars: Persistent Bugger. Need explanation + advice

Tags: java

http://www.codewars.com/kata/55bf01e5a717a0d57e0000ec/train/java

> Write a function, persistence, that takes in a positive parameter num and returns its multiplicative persistence, which is the number of times you must multiply the digits in num until you reach a single digit.
>   Eg: `39 = [3*9] = 27 = [2*7] = 14 = [1*4] = 4` therefore the output is 3 (the amount of steps)

I have attempted this KATA, and i am getting an error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
```

I am not sure why, please can anyone help? My code is below: i think the way i am handing this is far to complicated, but i have tried alternative routes but couldnt get any further with them. So this is what i have come up with: p.s. im new to java and development, i figure that you could use regression to come to the solution, but im not totally sure.

```
import java.util.LinkedList;

public class Persist {

  static LinkedList<Long> digits = new LinkedList<Long>();
  public static void splitNumbersUp(long number){
     while(number > 0) {
        digits.push(number % 10);
        number /= 10;
    }
  }

  public static void clearDigits(){
    digits.clear();
  }

  public static long multiply(int length){
    long variable = 0;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < digits.size(); i++){
      variable = digits.pop() * digits.pop();
      digits.push(variable);
    }

    return variable;
  }

    public static int persistence(long n) {
        long num = 0;
    if(n > 10){
          while(!((digits.get(0) / 10) >= 1)){ 
              splitNumbersUp(n);
              num = multiply(digits.size());
              clearDigits();
              digits.push(num);
          }

    int i = (int)digits.get(0).intValue();
    return i;
    }else{
    return 0;
  }

  }
}
```

Comment: hey, and welcome to SO
If the answer works and you are satisfied, please accept it as the right answer (This is different from voting it up ;) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this function is called first?

```
 public static int persistence(long n) {
    long num = 0;
    if(n > 10){
        while(!((digits.get(0) / 10) >= 1)){ 
            splitNumbersUp(n);
            num = multiply(digits.size());
            clearDigits();
            digits.push(num);
        }
...
```

In that case the Problem is that digits is empty, but you try to get an element of it.

If I am reading your code right, changing it to:

```
public static int persistence(long n) {
    long num = 0;
    splitNumbersUp(n); //This before the for loop
    if(n > 10){
          while(!((digits.get(0) / 10) >= 1)){ 
              splitNumbersUp(n);
              num = multiply(digits.size());
              clearDigits();
              digits.push(num);
          }
```

Should work